# Best Graphic Library to draw simple lines but with a lot of points which changes dynamically! (WPF)

Tags: wpf, graphics, line, points

I'd like to know a library to draw graphics in WPF..

I'd like to plot a line graph with a lot of points which increases at runtime..
I tried with DynamicDataDisplay, but it was very slow in my app...

So.. Can you suggest me a library / project to use to solve my problem?

Maaany thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest binding your data to a `System.Windows.Shapes.Path` using a converter, you just need to implement a notifying interface if points are added or removed to update the graph.
(Recently wrote a generic cartesian point array converter for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631231/wpf-path-drawing-and-data-binding/4631446#4631446))

Comment: So, how can I do to use the way you explained me? I've read the System.Windws.Shapes.Path class converter, but i don't know how to implement the converter, neither how to bind it to my graph... If i have understand: i had to creare an object which contains the Path.. The i have to bind my data to it using the converter you've written and the i've to implement the notifying interface.. Is this right? Can you suggest me how to start ?? ^^" Many thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, somehow i did not notice your comment in my in-box, do you still need help?