# What is the way to reuse a XAML DrawingImage changing only the PathGeometry LineSegments?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have three buttons in my WPF application that I want to display an image of a triangle.  I'm not using the Shape class because it's too heavyweight for my needs, so I'm using a DrawingImage instead.  Here is the markup for my image (I would post a clean-looking image but can't do it yet as I'm new):

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <DrawingImage>
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="LawnGreen">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="Black" Thickness="1" />
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathFigure   IsClosed="True">
                                <LineSegment Point="-10, 20" />
                                <LineSegment Point="30, 20" />
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

This is the image for the first button - a scalene triangle with its peak on the left.  The other two buttons' XAML are almost identical - the only change being the line segment points will be slightly different to peak in the middle and right of their axes, respectively.

How can I make one declaration for my Image.Source->DrawingImage as above only without the specific line segment coordinates, and then do something like

```
<Button>  
    <Image Source="MyGenericDrawingImage">  
        <!--*Fill in the PathGeometry>PathFigure> LineSegment coordinates for each button-->  
    </Image>  
</Button>
```

This would look much cleaner than having to dump blocks of nearly identical code all next to each other.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but here's the solution I used. I set the path geometry as a resource, and reference it as a style (great for re-use). To make the arrow point sideways, re-use the same icon and rotate it 90 degrees.

[image]

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<Page.Resources>
  <sys:String x:Key="Icon_ArrowDown">
          F1 M 4.439,0.000 L 2.219,3.112 L 0.000,0.000 L 4.439,0.000 Z
      </sys:String>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel> 

<Button>
   <Path Data="{StaticResource  Icon_ArrowDown}" Fill="Red" />
</Button>

<Button>
    <Path Data="{StaticResource Icon_ArrowDown}" Fill="Red" />
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90"/>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
</Button>

</StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have perfectly symmetrical, scaled, rotated geometry (etc), then you're going to have to resort to some sort of modification of the data to avoid "repeating" it.  It really is different geometry if it isn't congruent.

That said, you might be able to edit the data in code and use data binding to grab the edited values.

Here is some info on how to data bind a path to geometry specified in a view model:

[Path drawing and data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631231/path-drawing-and-data-binding/4631446#4631446)