# WPF - Path Geometry...Is there a way to bind the Data Property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, path, geometry

I have a `ControlTemplate` that serves as a "Bubble" popup on the `AdornerLayer` of a given control.

It works fine but I need to be able to calculate where it should display (middle/ bottom).

Instead of:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" Data="M 15 20 L 15 0 33 20" Margin="0 1 0 0"/>
```

I am looking for (obviously this won't work but it illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" Data="M {TemplateBinding Left} 20 L 15 0 33 20"/>
```

Can this be done with a `ValueConverter`?  I just can't visualize a solution for some reason.  I'm also open to alternatives.

Thanks for reading and if I can provide more info please just ask.

Comment: I may have found the answer here...but would like to see if anyone else has input?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631231/path-drawing-and-data-binding

Comment: this may helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/46349999/1468295

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a value converter that you can use to convert a string into the path data, you might like to try the [universal value converter](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/07/09/a-universal-value-converter-for-wpf.html) I wrote a while back.

Alternatively, to bind to a single property, you will have to expand your geometry by adding the various geometry objects into your XAML, rather than using the string shorthand. For example ...

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
  <Path.Data>
    <PathGeometry>
      <PathGeometry.Figures>
        <PathFigureCollection>
          <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="10,100">
            <PathFigure.Segments>
              <PathSegmentCollection>
                <LineSegment Point="{Binding MyPropertyPath}" />
                <LineSegment Point="100,50" />
              </PathSegmentCollection>
            </PathFigure.Segments>
          </PathFigure>
        </PathFigureCollection>
      </PathGeometry.Figures>
    </PathGeometry>
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: The link is dead.