# TemplateBinding of Button's Content into Path's Data

Tags: wpf

I got the following Button Style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Path Data="{TemplateBinding Content}" Fill="White" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

There is a Converter which converts some enum value to the wished data string of the path:

```
public class SugarOperationEnumToSolidImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var sugarOperationEnum = (SugarOperationEnum)value;

        switch (sugarOperationEnum)
        {
            case SugarOperationEnum.Increment:
                return CoffeeMachineIcons.PlusIcon;
            case SugarOperationEnum.Decrement:
                return CoffeeMachineIcons.MinusIcon;
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and a button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource SugarButtonStyle}"
                Content="{Binding DecrementSugarButtonContent, Converter={StaticResource SugarOperationEnumToSolidImageConverter}}"/>
```

For some reason the TemplateBinding of the Content of a button isn't working when I bind it into Data of a Path.

any Ideas how can I overcome this?

Comment: Why can't you try using `Style.Triggers` to set image as a content instead of `IValueConverter`?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Binding errors? Or simply nothing is shown ?

Comment: No errors and Binding errors. Nothing is shown.. it's funny because when I switch the path with:
 <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/> the string of the data is shown

Comment: @KaliTheGreat but is CoffeeMachineIcons.PlusIcon a geometry or simply a string?

Comment: @Babbillumpa It's a string...

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167763/wpf-path-geometry-is-there-a-way-to-bind-the-data-property

Comment: @KaliTheGreat Since Data is a Geometry object, not a string, you probably want to return a Geometry object using Geometry.Parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Geometry.Parse to bind Data, because Data is a Geometry and not a string, so you could modify your converter like this:

```
public class SugarOperationEnumToSolidImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var sugarOperationEnum = (SugarOperationEnum)value;

        switch (sugarOperationEnum)
        {
            case SugarOperationEnum.Increment:
                return Geometry.Parse(CoffeeMachineIcons.PlusIcon);
            case SugarOperationEnum.Decrement:
                return Geometry.Parse(CoffeeMachineIcons.MinusIcon);
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But consider to store the path as static resource rather parse them every time.