# Databinding shapes and lines in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, path, geometry, shapes

I am working on an application that needs to be able to manipulate shapes and lines in WPF.  My original thought was to databind a collection to ListBox and use Rectangles in the datatemplate, setting each of the fill properties to the image.  This has worked well for the majority of shapes, except for circles and a few rectangles.  Since re-sizing an image causes pixelation and the lines to change sizes, the result is less than stellar.

I have spent some time browsing SO and a few other sites regarding Path elements, but haven't found anything that really meets my needs.  My guess is I will need to generate paths differently for each type of shape and databind them using a converter similar to [Path drawing and data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631231/path-drawing-and-data-binding) or use http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/raddiagram-overview.html or similar rad tool.

My questions: Is there an easier way of accomplishing this or any other examples?

EDIT: I also need to be able to add text.  Not sure how I can do that with a path...maybe a ContentControl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw all manner of shapes by databinding a `Path.Data` to a `Geometry`. You can generate the `Geometry` from a list of points. A converter is perfect for this adaptation.

For example, I draw spirals by databinding the `Path.Data` property to a `StreamGeometry` which I generate off of a list of points managed by the view model, and it works quite well for my needs:

```
// ViewModel ...
public class ViewModel 
{
    [Notify]
    public IList<Point> Points { get; set; }
}

// Converter ... 
public class GeometryConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            return value;
        }

        var points = (IList<Point>)value;            
        var i = 0; 
        var newPath = new StreamGeometry();

        using (var context = newPath.Open())
        {
            var begun = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
            {
                var current = points[i];

                if (!begun)
                {
                    begun = true;
                    context.BeginFigure(current, true, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.ArcTo(current, new Size(radius, radius), angle, false, SweepDirection.Counterclockwise, true, true);
                }
            }
        }

        newPath.Freeze();
        return newPath.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Canvas>
    <Path StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeWidth}"
          Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}"
          Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}"
          Data="{Binding Points, Converter={StaticResource GeometryConverter}}">
        <Path.Stroke>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding CurrentColor}" />
        </Path.Stroke>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

As for the text, wouldn't it be better to bind `TextBlock` elements and arrange those on a 'Canvas` as needed?

Comment: Sorry for delay, but I'm pretty new to WPF.  I currently am using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85603/A-WPF-custom-control-for-zooming-and-panning?fid=1574482&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&spc=Relaxed&fr=1#xx0xx) for zooming and moving. You suggest using a textblock, but I don't see how to bind multiple elements of different types to the same ListBox.  The only thing i could think of is some sort of data template switch.

Comment: I changed my design a little bit, but was hoping to use your converter wrapped in a ContentControl.  I just added your converter and noticed that radius and angle do not exist.  Is this logic that I need to add based on the shape?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. I tore this out of some existing code which uses those values. They are not really needed, and you'd likely not need them if you are just building straight line shapes: you'd only need the point list and call `context.LineTo`. If you did need curves, you'd need some way to define what the points in the list are, so the correct method on `context` could be called.

Comment: codekaizen, I ended up using multiple datatemplates instead and specifying shapes inside of ContentControls.  This worked with the exception of lines.  For lines, I forced the x and y to equal 0 and then used a line start/end coordinates with thumbs to allow for dragging.  Thanks for all of your help, it was just a little more than I needed.